# Firebase publisher subscriber

Tags: java, android, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

Firebase If subscriber is subscribed to a topic before publisher subscribes and pushes to the topic , can Firebase deliver message to subscriber after publisher pushes message ?
In my app I have a scenario where if subscriber subscribes to a topic first before publisher adds to that topic and sends message , I should be able to send that message to initially added subscriber.

Comment: Are you talking about Realtime Database?  There are no "topics", "pushes", or "messages" when working with that.

Answer (score 0):

If i understand well your request, according to the documentation, the messages sent to a topic are received only after the device has suscribed. So, it doesn't receive messages that were sent to the topic when it isn't subscribed.
Also:

> Client apps can subscribe to any existing topic, or they can create a
>   new topic. When a client app subscribes to a new topic name (one that
>   does not already exist for your Firebase project), a new topic of that
>   name is created in FCM and any client can subsequently subscribe to
>   it.

Comment: true. And one more scenario I want to know. (I checked it as well with POC. still wanted to confirm). If publisher pushes a message to topic, then subscriber subscribes, then can that subscriber gets the pushed message from that topic queue because that message is pushed to the queue before he subscribed.

Comment: No. New subscribers will not receive the message.

Comment: If this helped you, please mark as answered so other people can find it easily. Thank you.